# Use a taglike system for SE-sites in the Hot Network Questions

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions

I suggest it should be made possible to highlight and hide/grey-out some SE-sites in the hot network questions, just like we can do with the specific tags on SE-sites.

Comment: @rene Simular for sure, but not a complete duplicate. I'm not only suggesting to exclude sites, but also highlight them or grey them out. Just like the tagsystem.